# Assignment to multidimensional array in julia

Tags: multidimensional-array, variable-assignment, julia

The following simple piece of code returns, what seems to me, an unexpected result:

```
srand(101)

# create a multidimensional array that will house 3 matrices of dimensions 2x2
A = Array(Array{Float64,2},3)

# initialise array with zero matrices (is this the culprit?)
fill!(A, zeros(2,2))

# populate array (some dummy computation to illustrate my problem)
for ii=1:2
   for jj=1:2
      aux = randn(1,3)
      for dd=1:3
         A[dd][ii,jj]=aux[dd]
      end
   end
end
```

When I run the above code, my array A reads:

```
3-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}:
 2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.2821   -2.10146
 -1.00158   1.8163 
 2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.2821   -2.10146
 -1.00158   1.8163 
 2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.2821   -2.10146
 -1.00158   1.8163
```

Why are the the three 2x2 matrices identical when I am actually creating them randomly?

I do understand that one has to be careful when assigning arrays to arrays in Julia, but somehow the error eludes me.

The funny thing I discovered is that if I initialise A like follows:

```
for dd=1:3
   A[dd] = zeros(2,2)
end
```

as opposed to with

```
fill!(A, zeros(2,2))
```

like above, then I get what I consider the correct result:

```
3-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}:
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
-0.176283   0.22073 
-1.71021   -0.575144
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
1.94395   1.09946 
1.65326  -0.446783    
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
1.2821   -2.10146
-1.00158   1.8163
```

Note that the last matrix is the matrix that is repeating above.

Is it the array initialisation that is wrong, or the assignment?
I guess it is the combination of the two, depending on how exactly you do them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost answered it yourself. Yes,

```
fill!(A, zeros(2,2))
```

is the culprit, after the command each cell of A contains the *same* array (is connected to the same 2x2 spot in memory). The function `zeros` gets called once.

Filling the cells of the array in a loop

```
for dd=1:3
   A[dd] = zeros(2,2)
end
```

calls the function `zeros` 3 times, returning a *different* zero array for each cell (located at different positions in memory).

Comment: The same `for` in array comprehension form: `A = [zeros(2,2) for i=1:3]`. Comprehension is very convenient for these multi-dimensional initializations, especially since you can iterate over several indices in the same comprehension. Perhaps using a 3-dim array instead of vector of 2-dim arrays is better (if their sizes are the same).

Comment: Ok, I see the problem with the _same array_. In danger of sounding a bit disparaging, this makes function fill!() unhelpful in such cases. The suggested comprehension is perhaps a nice possibility. Are there perhaps other ways of initialising multi-dimensional arrays? Thanks.

Comment: It's not an issue if you fill with an immutable array, e.g., from FixedSizeArrays.